# Is expo-sqlite on Android different than iOS?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

The following issues are ONLY on Android, NOT on iOS. I'm using Expo CLI 5.5.1 with a managed workflow.

My app needs to store all data on the user's device so I chose SQLite, using expo-sqlite.

I have a backup/restore system set up and when I use it on iOS, everything works well. I can:

1. export the database to an external location (e.g. iCloud)
2. delete the database located at FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/db.db'
3. verify the database no longer exists
4. import the database from the external location and place it back into the above location
5. reload the app

The above works just fine (I can skip steps 2 & 3 on iOS).

When I am on Android, the above doesn't work. When I follow the above steps the restored database is nothing more than the original database I created when the app first loads after a new install (the 'factory default' database).

It seems that after the initial database is created on Android, all further changes are stored somewhere else. I can add data from within the app, reload the app, see the changes previously made, export that database, then import it again, when I do this I don't see the changes, I only see the 'factory default' database.

Again, these issues are ONLY on Android, iOS works fine.

Comment: How did you export the database to an external location? Did you use `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync`? I'm trying to do similar thing, but I can't figure out how to maintain the db extension since the `FileSystem` converts the file into Base64 format.

Comment: @snowrain My app uses Expo so I use their `import * as Sharing from "expo-sharing";`. I also zip up the database so users can password  protect it if they want. So my setup is: 1) copy the database to a new location I set (it doesn't matter where inside the app directory structure, but not doing this would cause problems). 2) zip the copied db file with 'react-native-zip-archive' (this step is probably not needed if you don't zip anything). 3) run `Sharing.shareAsync(targetPath, { 'public.item' });` (where targetPath is the path to the zip file). 4) delete the copied db file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Have you solved this issue where it doesn't work on Android?